# Eclipse Plugin:Opening a view in eclipse and if the view is already present then update it.

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have one viewId and this is what I am trying to do. The only problem is the view is not getting refreshed if it is already open.

```
 String viewId="";
 IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                        .getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
   IViewReference[] references =page.getViewReferences();
for (IViewReference ivr :references) {
  if (ivr.getId().equalsIgnoreCase(viewId)) {
    page.hideView(ivr); //if already open then hide it
    break;
   }
}
//open a new instance
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage().showView(viewId);
```

Comment: Is the view your code? If so rather than close the view I would make the view use `IPartListener` to be notified when it is activated.

Comment: yes, the view is a part of my code. But I didn't understand how IPartListener will help in current situation.